# AppJar: TclError: invalid command name ".!menu"

Tags: python, tkinter

My game consistently hits the same error code when the application is attempting to open (I am almost certain the issue lays with the app.start as when I seem to take it out the gui opens. However I then get a whole nother range of issues which I shouldn't be dealing with.) I'm doing this in a class and all of my peers seem to have almost identical, if not identical code to mine yet as per this section and theres all seems to work? Thank you so much if you're able to either find out why my code is not running: (probably me just missing something obvious, I'm an especially new to python and programming in general)

```
from appJar import gui
from turtle import *

people = ['Lachlan', 'Adrian', 'George', 'Aban', 'Joseph', 'Emulka', 'Shaniqua', 'Requise']
colours = ['red', 'yellow', ' cyan', 'purple', 'brown', 'black', 'white', 'blue']

def game ():
    app.go()
    bgcolor("light green")
    title("RACING TURTLES")
    speed(12)
    penup()
    goto(-160,110)
    counter_names = 0
    y = 100
    while counter_names < 8:         
        people[counter_names] = Turtle()
        people[counter_names].colour(colours[counter_names])
        people[counter_names].shape('turtle')
        people[counter_names].penup()
        people[counter_names].goto(160, y)
        people[counter_names].pendown()
        counter_names = counter_names + 1
        y = y - 20

game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define `app`.

After some experimenting (I'm not familiar with turtle), the following works for me:

```
from appJar import gui
from turtle import *

people = ['Lachlan', 'Adrian', 'George', 'Aban', 'Joseph', 'Emulka', 'Shaniqua', 'Requise']
colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'purple', 'brown', 'black', 'white', 'blue']

def game():
        bgcolor("light green")
        title("RACING TURTLES")
        speed(12)
        penup()
        goto(-160,110)
        counter_names = 0
        y = 100
        while counter_names < 8:         
            people[counter_names] = Turtle()
            people[counter_names].color(colours[counter_names])
            people[counter_names].shape('turtle')
            people[counter_names].penup()
            people[counter_names].goto(160, y)
            people[counter_names].pendown()
            counter_names = counter_names + 1
            y = y - 20

game()

with gui('mygame') as app:
    app.go()
```